# Will stainless bolts rust more or less than zinc plated when installed in cast iron?

Tags: well-pump, corrosion, galvanic-corrosion

Scenario:

I have a 3-seasons ocean side cottage which sources its water from a shallow well via a convertible jet pump with a cast-iron casing/housing.

I winterize the water system each fall and the pump sits dry in the winter. The water is quite rusty so I always need to clean out the impeller and housing area as the rust hardens and dries.

The standard zinc bolts rust badly within 1 season and are a huge pain to pull out during the yearly rebuild. Because of that, I was thinking about using stainless steel bolts instead of the normal zinc ones to hold the cast-iron pump casing and head to the motor.

**Will there be more, or less, corrosion (on bolts, and on the cast iron head) with stainless bolts in cast iron vs. zinc bolts in cast iron?**

Comment: Sounds like a good experiment using however many varieties of bolts you can find. Using stainless would get rid of the electrochemical issues of different metals though.

Comment: Yep, but I am not looking for an experiment, but rather, I want to make my life easier each spring when I pull the pump head off to clean out the dried up rust deposits from sitting dry all winter.

Comment: The bolts will not be the only thing corroding. It seems you need a pump designed for sea water ; aluminum bronze, monel , etc.

Comment: Since pulling the pump and cleaning it internally seems to be part of your yearly ritual, doing a one-time experiment with multiple different bolt types really does seem to be an ideal way to figure out what will work best in _your_ particular situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stainless bolts will not get the surface oxidation that the Zink bolts did.
There will still be some rust from the cast iron and of course calcification depending on the waters' mineral content.

That still will be easier on disassembly, as the minerals will not harden well against the stainless.

With all the benefits of the stainless bolts you will still have the gradual degradation of the iron pump surfaces. However you greatly reduce the likely hood of the broken bolt and the accompanying headaches.